# SharePoint 2013 - Send alert when someone "like" a list item

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow, sharepoint-list

Is there an easy way to set up SharePoint 2013 alerting the list item creator when someone like his item? 
I was wondering if that could be achieved via workflow - any ideas?

Thanks